# Binary search algorithm actual number of searches in average

Tags: binary-search

I know the time complexity of binary search algorithm is O(nlogn).

But what is the average number of searches using binary search algorithm?

I don't know whether which to use between the floor of nlogn or ceiling of nlogn.

> For a sorted array that contains 11 items, what is the average
>   number of searches using a binary search algorithm? (Assume
>   that all searches are successful in finding the item)

How can I determine the average number of search with binary search algorithm?

Thanks for your help in advance.